# C++ | How to remove the DataSource from a combobox?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clr, windows-forms-designer

I'm writing a windows forms application in visual studio with c++ and CLR.
And now, i got the following problem:

I read in a file and save all the important informations in a vector.

With a second step, i convert all items to a CLR array and set this array as DataSource.

```
array<System::String^>^ PREDEFINED = gcnew array <System::String^>(OP->CIS_Values[OP->selectedCIS]->PREDEFINED_order.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < OP->CIS_Values[OP->selectedCIS]->PREDEFINED_order.size(); i++) {
                    PREDEFINED[i] = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(OP->CIS_Values[OP->selectedCIS]->PREDEFINED_order[i]);
                }
                this->comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataSource = PREDEFINED;
                this->comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->SelectedIndex = -1;
                delete PREDEFINED;
```

After setting the DataSource, it must be possible to remove it. In C# i can do this with

```
comboBox.DataSource = null;
```

but how does it work in C++?

I tried the following cases:

```
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataSource = NULL;
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataSource = 0;
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataSource = -1;

comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataBindings->Clear();
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->Items->Clear();
```

I tried it with DataBindings before and after DataSource, but i always get the same exception:

System.ArgumentException: "The complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either IList or IListSource"

How can i fix this issue ?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ CLR you only need to write:

```
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->DataSource = nullptr;
```

and you don't need to write

```
comboBox_header_predefinedtypes->Items->Clear();
```

after removing the DateSource to delete the items.